# How to set the contract address for deploying smart contract with frontend

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, smartcontracts

I try to clone this project and try to deploy. Project is: https://github.com/metodi96/nftrees.git In this smart contracts are successfully deployed but have change testnet or use ganache. In my case I have get the error from frontend part.

I try to add contract address via using ganache lochal network and also sepolia testnet, but if I run frontend to compiling it gives this error.

how to fix this error and add contract address?

[image]